# CodeIgniter "default_controller" functions without controller name in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Forgive me if this is a "duh" question or if you need more information to answer, I am new to CodeIgniter and still haven't figured out a few things with best practices and such...

In `routes.php` I have `$route['default_controller'] = "home";` so my `default_controller` is obviously "home".

Inside my `home.php` controller I have:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        // blah
    }
    function index(){
        // blah
    }
    function login(){
        // blah
    }
}
```

Which works fine and everything, there is no problems with that. The only thing I can't figure out is if I want to access the `login` function, I currently have to go to www.blah.com/home/login. **How can I change it so it just goes to www.blah.com/login, without creating a new controller** *(I would like to keep some of these one time base urls all in my default controller)*? Is that even possible or do I just have to create a new controller?

If I just have to create a new one, is there a best practices for how many controllers you have, etc.

Comment: I found that I can do "$route['login'] = '/home/login';" as a route to fix this, but is that the correct way? Is there a better way?

Comment: well .. the routes are the way to go if you don't like CI standard route behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Documentation says:** This route will tell the Router what URI segments to use if those provided in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.

So use `$route['login'] = 'home/login';`

Answer (score 0):

The way I have it set up is to have the `index` function act as the gatekeeper: if not logged in, show a login form `view`, if logged in, redirect to your (protected) home page. The `login` function is only accessed via `post`, when the user submits his login/pwd, and performs the login logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need add a line to your `application/config/routes.php` file

```
$route['login'] = "home/login";
```